# Insert a component on the curved line in circuitikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Please consider the below MWE:

```
\documentclass[border={1mm},multi=circuitikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[europeanresistors,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}

\coordinate (N1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (N2) at (0,-4);
\coordinate (N3) at (-4,-4);
\coordinate (N4) at (0,-8);

\draw (N1)to [R,o-o](N2);
\draw (N2)to [R,o-o](N4);
\draw (N4)to [R,o-o](N3);
\draw (N3)to [R,o-o](N1);
\draw (N2)to [R,o-o](N3);
\draw (N1)to [R,o-o,bend left=60](N4);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

But there is no component on the curved line!?

Comment: Circuitikz components are only positioned on straight paths. You can superpose one on a generic path using the `node` for, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be like this

```
\documentclass[border={1mm},multi=circuitikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[europeanresistors,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}

\coordinate (N1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (N2) at (0,-4);
\coordinate (N3) at (-4,-4);
\coordinate (N4) at (0,-8);

\draw (N1)to [R,o-o](N2);
\draw (N2)to [R,o-o](N4);
\draw (N4)to [R,o-o](N3);
\draw (N3)to [R,o-o](N1);
\draw (N2)to [R,o-o](N3);
\draw (N1)to  [bend left] (2,-3) to[R] (2,-5) to [bend left] (N4);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```